# Updating expiration through API in quay

Tags: quay.io

I am working with an inhouse quay 3.3.0, and I am looking for a way to use the API to set a new expiration date on an image.

The API explorer isn't that helpful but I can see that the frontend uses the REST service
PUT [https://quay.at.home/api/v1/repository/{organization}/{repository}/tag/{version}](https://quay.at.home/api/v1/repository/%7Borganization%7D/%7Brepository%7D/tag/%7Bversion%7D)

But I can't seem to find any credentials that give me anything else than a 403. I have tried with an application token and my own auth token to no effect.

How do I call the API, and with which credentials?